# Changing laravel route based on form select

Tags: laravel

I have 3 routes in a laravel project

- Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
- Route::get('/videos', 'VideoController@index');
- Route::get('/movies', 'MoviesController@index');

I have created a settings model & migration where the admin can select the home page. Now what I want to achieve is based on the selection, the route should be set as home page.

Eg: If admin selects example.com/videos as Home Page then videos should be accessed on example.com/

Comment: uhm simply save the route or url to the database, and show it at will? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a single route with an optional parameter and a HomeController with an index function, the index function should accept a parameter which could either be video,movies then you use a switch case to check if it is video or music or the home route

Route::get('/{data?}', 'HomeController@index');

public function index(Request $request, $data = null){
//use a switch case to check if it is video, or music

}

Comment: I had already implemented the above. But how to make it reflect in the url ? Selecting the home page as videos will make homepage as example.com/videos but not example.com

Comment: You can add each of the variables as a parameter to the route.

Answer (score 0):

@PuneetKarajagi You can add each of the variables as a parameter to the route. for instance your route for the video will be 
route('home', ['data' => 'video']); and the route for movies will be 
route('home', ['data' => 'movies']);

Comment: thnx! I achieved by returning the view for route('/), I create a db column as is_home and then added if(is_home == 1)  return view('/')  & if(is_home == 2) return view('/videos),  - Is it a good practice ?